# Does taking altitude out of the equation helps in Augmented Reality apps

Tags: android, geolocation, augmented-reality, location-based-service

I'm developing a Geo-based AR application on Android and was disappointed with the POIs shown irrelevantly to the ground,, since I want it to always be shown on the ground (Altitude 0).
do you think it's a good idea to take the altitude out of the equation for both POIs and the user.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from what i've seen, it is not really the problem, the main one is facing the POI. Then you can worry about the altitude.

And in some cases, you will be fixing POIs at a far distance, it means they will be displayed all together on the horizon, not very pleasant for the user.

It's up to you if you want to implement the altitude. When I began developing this kind of augmented reality I wanted to use altitude, but in my case, I download POIs data from a server, and the altitude is not provided, only altitude and longitude.

The trick I use is that I display nearest POIs at the bottom of the screen and the furthest ones at the top, while taking care of the heading. In addition, I scale the annotations and add some perspective respectively to the distance and heading.

You can have an illustration [here](http://gigaom.com/mobile/old-lumias-get-nokias-new-city-lens-augmented-reality-app/), the result is nice!

As you can see it is no problem, taking altitudes out of the equation.